# Accessing Objects Attributes Within Ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I am adding ajax to my website. I originally had this button:

```
{% for item in notifications %}
    <a class='delete' href="{% url 'delete' item.slug %}">
```

But changed it to Ajax.

```
{% for item in notifications %}
    <a class='delete'>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users/ajax/delete/',
        data: {
          // here I was to call the 'delete' function in the 'django.notifications' package
          // something like 'notifications.delete(slug)'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Working");
        }
    });
});
```

This Ajax fires correctly, but I don't know how to get item.slug in Ajax. I guess I could do this `<a class='delete' slug="{{ item.slug }}">` and access the `slug`, but it seems really sloppy.

Is there a way to pass an object's attributes to Ajax without setting it as a value within the html code itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of the notification in a variable while rendering the HTML as shown below in the HTML section. Once you have notifications value in your script code. You can check the index of the clicked anchor and retrieve the item associated with that index.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
  let elem = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/users/ajax/delete/',
    data: {
      // here I was to call the 'delete' function in the 'django.notifications' package
      // something like 'notifications.delete(slug)'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Working");

      //new code below
      let index = $("a.delete").index(elem);
      let item = notifications[index];
      //You can access slug and other attributes of item now.
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script>
const notifications = {% notifications %}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see how your solution should work, however the html causes an issue. I get two errors "Property assignment expected", and "Expression expected" when I try to assign the notifications. I remember trying to assign things in Django using <script> tag a while ago and couldn't get it to work and concluded that it couldn't be done. I'm guessing I am wrong though. Does my problem assigning ```const notifications = {% notifications %}``` make any sense to you? Thank you.

Comment: @Brenden Just make sure that you convert notifications in a JS array instead of django list. The error could be because of that. Or maybe convert the datatype from django to JS